# Старт активити с PageAdapter

Tags: java, android, activity

Main.java

```
public class MainDD extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ViewPager mSlideViewPager;
    private LinearLayout mDotsLayout;
    private swipeDD sliderAdapter;
    private ImageView imag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_dd);

        mSlideViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.slideViewPager);
        mDotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dotsLayout);

        sliderAdapter = new swipeDD(this);
        mSlideViewPager.setAdapter(sliderAdapter);

        imag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slide_image1);
        imag.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

        public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.slide_image1:
                Intent readMore = new Intent(v.getContext(), actDD1.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(readMore);
        }
    }
}
```

pageadapter.java

```
public class swipeDD extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public swipeDD(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int[] slide_images = {
            R.drawable.dd3,
            R.drawable.mainbg,
            R.drawable.mainbg
    };

    public String[] slide_headings = {
            "Daredevil",
            " ",
            "Ooo"
    };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return slide_headings.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject( View view, Object o)  {
        return view == (RelativeLayout) o;
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem( ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slidedd, container, false);

        ImageView slideImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_image1);
        TextView slideHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_heading);

        slideImageView.setImageResource(slide_images[position]);
        slideHeading.setText(slide_headings[position]);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position,  Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
    }
}
```

Использую картинку как кнопку, каким способом можно перейти на новую активити, во всех остальных случаях не рабоатает

Comment: что и как не работает?

Comment: кнопка не работает,  пишет обращается в 0

Comment: если у вас появляется какая-то ошибка - приведите стэктрейс и, вероятно, разметку. Пока не понятно, что конкретно вы хотите и что конкретно у вас не получается

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, у вас не запускается новое активити по нажатию на картинку, если это так, то попробуйте поменять:

```
 Intent readMore = new Intent(v.getContext(), actDD1.class);
```

на

```
Intent readMore = new Intent(MainDD.this, actDD1.class);
```

- также проверьте, что у вас прописано активити 'actDD1' в манифесте